# Regex: replace newline except the ones with a dot

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, newline

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

I have a text like that:

```
Bla bla bla bl[CR][LF]
a bla bla bla[CR][LF]
bla bla.[CR][LF]
Bla bla bla bla bl[CR][LF]
...and so on
```

I'd like to replace all new lines except the ones having a dot as last character.

This is the what I wanna get to:

```
Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.[CR][LF]
Bla bla bla bla bla.[CR][LF]
...and so on
```

I tried with Notepad++, that supports RegEx, using the Search & Replace tab (Ctrl+H). That's the code:

```
Search:   [^.\r\n]\r\n
Replace field had just a space.
```

It worked, but it truncates the last character of every line.

```
Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bl.[CR][LF]
Bla bla bla bla bl.[CR][LF]
```

As I am a RegEx novice, which is the best way to do that?

Comment: Do you want the deleted CRLF replaced by nothing or a blank?  The desired output illustrates both (the `bl` at the end of the first input line is joined to the `a` at the start of the second, but the `bla` at the end of the second is separated from the `bla` at the start of the third by a blank).  You can have either behaviour, but not both without a detailed explanation of when the the replacement is an empty string and when the blank is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex: `(?<!\.)\r\n` in the search field. It means find any `\r\n` that isn't preceded by a `.`.

Your regex means find any three characters where the first one isn't a `.` `\r` or `\n`, and the last two are `\r\n`. But then when you go to replace, it replaces that 1st character as well. The regex I posted checks for the non-period as a zero-length, so it doesn't replace that character.